# React.useEffect hook and subscribing to a mousewheel event - the right approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, eslint

**The goal:**

1. Subscribe to the mousewheel `event` once, at component mount.
2. Update the state.scrollTop of the component with `newValue`, where:

`newValue = Math.max(0, state.scrollTop + event.deltaY)`

3. Keep react hooks linter happy without disabling default rules.

**The code:**

```
  const [ state, setState ] = useState({ scrollTop: 0 });

  useEffect(function subscribeToWheelEvent() {
    const updateScroll = function(e) {
      if(!!e.deltaY) {
        const delta = Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 10.0;
        const val = Math.max(0, state.scrollTop + delta);
        console.log(delta, val);
        setState({ scrollTop: val })
      } else {
        console.log('zero', e.deltaY);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', updateScroll);
    console.log('subscribed to wheelEvent')
    return function () {
      window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', updateScroll);
    }
  }, []);
```

**Expected result:**

The `state.scrollTop` value updates every mouse wheel event by +-10 depending on scroll direction and is capped at 0 if `newValue` is smaller than 0.

**Current result:**

The `state.scrollTop` value does not update properly, switches between 0 and 10, probably because it is memoized inside the `updateScroll` and remains at 0.

The linter informs me that I should include state.scrollTop as dependency of the effect but I don't want that as it should be executing only once at component mount.

Following the linter causes infinite loop.

Alternatively, moving `updateScroll` outside of subscription function, then as per linter suggestions, adding `updateScroll` to dependencies, and (again following the linter) wrapping `updateScroll` with `useCallback(updateScroll, [state.scrollTop] )` results in subscribing/unsubscribing to the wheel event on every `scrollTop` change.

**Alternative code:**

```
  const [ state, setState ] = useState({ scrollTop: 0 });

  const updateScroll = useCallback(function(e) {
    if(!!e.deltaY) {
      const delta = Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 10.0;
      const val = Math.max(0, state.scrollTop + delta);
      console.log(delta, val );
      setState({ scrollTop: val })
    } else {
      console.log('zero', e.deltaY);
    }
  }, [ state.scrollTop ])

  useEffect(function subscribeToWheelEvent() {
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', updateScroll);
    console.log('subscribed to wheelEvent')
    return function () {
      window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', updateScroll);
      console.log('unsubscribed to wheelEvent')
    }
  }, [ updateScroll ]);
```

**Question:**

How to achieve the goal?

Comment: There are some edge cases, where linters have no preferred option for. I think for what you're trying to accomplish, you need to use your first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of closing over the `state` variable in your `useEffect` handler you can pass a function to the `setState`.

The parameter of the function is the current state and you need to return the new state. This way the linter should not complain as your `useEffect` does not depend on the state variable.

Something like:

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState({ scrollTop: 0 });

useEffect(function subscribeToWheelEvent() {
const updateScroll = function(e) {
  if(!!e.deltaY) {
    setState((currentState)=>{
         const delta = Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 10.0;
         const val = Math.max(0, currentState.scrollTop + delta);
         return {scrollTop:val}   
    })            
  }

  } else {
    console.log('zero', e.deltaY);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', updateScroll);
console.log('subscribed to wheelEvent')
return function () {
  window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', updateScroll);
}
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of problems:

1. I don't have a mousewheel, but the event `mousewheel` is deprecated - you might want to use something else. I subscribed to the `scroll` event.
2. I'm not absolutely sure what you're trying to calculate with delta and val, but  `const val = Math.max(0, state.scrollTop + delta)` didn't seem to work as expected for me. Did you mean to calculate the CURRENT scrollTop value, not the stored one?. Either way, this was what was causing your value to return as `10` and is what was causing the re-rendering loop.

So I think this is what you're after:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ scrollTop: 0 })

const updateScroll = useCallback(() => {
  if (window.pageYOffset) {
    const delta = Math.sign(window.pageYOffset) * 10.0
    const val = Math.max(0, window.pageYOffset + delta)
    setState({ scrollTop: val })
  } else {
    console.log('zero', window.pageYOffset)
  }
}, [])

useEffect(
  function subscribeToWheelEvent () {
    console.log('subscribed to wheelEvent')
    window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScroll)
    return function () {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', updateScroll)
    }
  },
  [updateScroll]
)

console.log(state.scrollTop)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I have to handle mousewheel here.

Comment: Cool - well same applies for the rest. The mousewheel event should still work :)